# Animation being interrupted because ofanother animation

Tags: android, animation

This is not the first time i found this issue.
If you play an animation at the same time than another, it stops randomly.

```
halfPie.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ValueAnimator animator = new ValueAnimator();
                        animator.setObjectValues(0, 100);
                        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                                halfPie.setCenterText(String.valueOf(animation.getAnimatedValue()));
                            }
                        });
                        animator.setDuration(10000); // here you set the duration of the anim
                        animator.start();

                    }
                });
```

This animation is being interrupted by halfPie animation. (Pd: It has an animation itself that shows up the entire object from invisible to visible)

Note: I know you can listen to onAnimationEnd but i want them to play together. (That doesnt mean to use AnimationSet)

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in Your application tag AndroidManifest.xml file

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

I hope this will solve your Problem

Comment: Not working mate! I tried to put it on Application level and Activity level. But i think it could be a good approach. Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed that i needed: 

```
public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                                halfPie.setCenterText(String.valueOf(animation.getAnimatedValue()));
                                halfPie.invalidate();
                            }
```

The animation of halfPie itself was doing an invalidate() so the animation was playing but in an old halfPie draw that it wasnt already in the screen.

So, the solution is just to trigger invalidate each time.